# Fast joining two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two DataFrames:

```
date                    value
2019-09-12 17:10:31      1
2019-09-12 17:10:31      0.5
2019-09-12 17:10:35      2
2019-09-12 17:10:36      1
.                        .
.                        .
.                        .
```

And second one:

```
date1                    value1
2019-09-12 17:10:22      0.2
2019-09-12 17:10:24      0.3
2019-09-12 17:10:30      0.002
2019-09-12 17:10:46      0.11
.                        .
.                        .
.                        .
```

To the first df I would like to add column with information about sum of the value1 from "date - 60 seconds" to "date". I did something like that:

```
def volume_traded(df, interval, df1):
    return df.date.apply(lambda x: get_volume_in_interval(x, interval, df1))


def get_volume_in_interval(time, interval, df1):
    temp = df1[(df1.date1 < time) & (df1.date1 > time - 
datetime.timedelta(seconds=interval))]
    return temp.value.sum()
```

This solution is really really slow (I say about dataframes that have approximately 20-50k rows

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy` broadcast

```
s1=df1.date.values
s2=df2.date1.values
s=(s1-s2[:,None])/np.timedelta64(1, 's')
((s<0)&(s>-60)).dot(df2.value1)
Out[94]: array([0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.612])
```